# Splitting double quatation comma lines in java

Tags: java, split

I try to split

> "11020199,Abc Germany ,aduz,,444,bieb,dc,2   ,2222.00,whatever 5dc,222.22,22.00,""98,00"",""12,00"",21-09-2018,06:00               "

It has double quotation only when theres a comma in the string, otherwise its seperated by just the comma and theres no double quotation. 
How do i split this line properly? I've seen how to split it when everything is double quotated but not when its only done when theres a comma.

Comment: Do you need any of the double quotes after splitting?

Comment: theres no \n involved btw, it just went further on another line because its written without spaces

Comment: @deHaar no I do not

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: you need a csv API not a "double quatation comma lines".... correctly identifying the problem is the first step to correclty solving... all the bellow answer might solve your problem but are "redefining the wheel"

Comment: @RafaelLima sure, in general, it would be better to have a semicolon separated formatting if there may be values that have a comma as part of them. But maybe, OP has no influence on that, then it comes to *redefining the wheel*, doesn't it?

Comment: doesn't matter how you decide to do... CSV is well stabilished standard there are tons of apis to handle this problem, anything in here is useless effort

Comment: I totally disagree on that @RafaelLima . If there's only 10 lines of code needed to read the csv, why use an api? It's totally bs.

Comment: @BeastJulian, because you dont need to test, tweak and lot of stuff since this is a whole well known and old standard, he is showing one case, but csv has way more scenarios that if you just consider all of them are going to be like this you will fail

Comment: That doesn't counter my argument honestly @RafaelLima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example solution could be this, which takes care of the comma in double quoted values being kept:

Split the `String` by comma first and use the double quotes in order to merge their values afterwards:

```
public class SplitAndKeepQuotedValuesCommas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String source = "11020199,Abc Germany ,aduz,,444,bieb,dc,2 ,2222.00,whatever 5dc,222.22,22.00,\"\"98,00\"\",\"\"12,00\"\",21-09-2018,06:00";

        // split the String by comma
        String[] justValues = source.split(",");

        // print all items in the result
        for (String s : justValues) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        // prepare a List for all the values
        List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();

        // then go through the values
        for (int i = 0; i < justValues.length; i++) {
            // and check if there is a String that begins with double double quotes
            if (justValues[i].startsWith("\"\"")) {
                /*
                 * if there is one, remove the double quotes from it and its successor,
                 * then concatenate them with a comma in between and add the result to the list
                 */
                String merged = justValues[i].replace("\"\"", "") + "," + justValues[i + 1].replace("\"\"", "");
                resultList.add(merged);
            /*
             * since there are still values with trailing double double quotes,
             * only add values without because they have already been added inside the merged value
             */
            } else if (!justValues[i].endsWith("\"\"")) {
                resultList.add(justValues[i]);
            }
        }

        resultList.forEach(value -> {
            System.out.println(value);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the same solution which i provided

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem. Here a possible solution (although I'm not really happy with it myself..)

```
String str = "11020199,Abc Germany ,aduz,,444,bieb,dc,2 ,2222.00,whatever 5dc,222.22,22.00,\"\"98,00\"\",\"\"12,00\"\",21-09-2018,06:00";

// Replace the comma between double quotes with a replacement char you're sure isn't in the String:
// TODO: Use a more suitable character, I don't know what your text can/cannot contain
String modifiedStr = str.replaceAll("(\"\"[^,]+),([^,]+\"\")", "$1$2");

// Now split by comma:
String[] array = modifiedStr.split(",");

// And then change the replacement char back again to a comma:
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
  array[i] = array[i].replace("", ",");
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##ZVJtjtMwEP3fU4yslTZR3DSJCqIt@6MSEuIHLKLwqy2Sk3hbbxM7OE67Ae0ROAP34FTcoIydZNXVRoo/Zt7Y7z3PPTuy8X1@OJ@zgtU1fGRC/hoBVE1aiAxqwwxORyVyKDHlrYwWcrfeAvMtDKALIFDDDZA4jpIons3oMs3gPdclky1Qljc/KZ1OpzQVPKV5RhOgCX5hFNHTnhl@5Bpe2TjGkoR2mQ3ZkNkbGkV24XZxMuySeBzNxngX5l/Po4gsHBs3TCbwhVcFyziYPYdMlSWDlJsT5xJyhco4/GiU4TWchNkDA93BSy4NZHumoVXNteZQNziIWl4bENId1smdX0ovVS7uBM9XzgI0IuyPWxaFRzxLd/2dbgOfem62AZ9QIFfxvz@//14lxF9Yzl9v393O4VvNkVCp3O3CMEvWUmKZ4ZrCBxRg6RykOoG1zlLVYPgDMmdygr9UuFTS4HONBj8@IbquCmEgbTtDLiXY59SatUj/QkzoCjxCkd/TQUuZWx@k5SR3ncEv3EtZdgC2QwLdLXdKewKT4iZagHjr7goLLndmj/sg8B0KOhJrsUUew3Lw0iPWK@uao/P01pXmxrSfUYVZ2hLPFTrE48hhLlv4Bfq5/uctbZQD2rZeb2TfYFZKnxeGlzDvK3sFQ02ARQAbQgKLClz/DkdcYrZ9bNXWiAtVY8LKJgvp9bBeyuP5/B8)

NOTE: Assumes the values between double double-quotes will only contain a single comma.

Comment: Good answer, but the one i accepted is more complete.. I'm sorry but appreciate your effort man was hard to choose :')

Comment: @BeastJulian Np. The one you accepted is probably easier to read as well, so I can understand the accepted mark.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below [You can improve extracting some part to some method, but this will work for you anyway]

```
    String[] splittedData = s.split(",");
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>(splittedData.length);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String splittedDataPart : splittedData) {
        splittedDataPart = splittedDataPart.trim();
        if (sb.length() == 0 && !splittedDataPart.startsWith("\"")) {
            data.add(splittedDataPart);
            continue;
        }

        if (sb.length() != 0)
            sb.append(",");
        sb.append(splittedDataPart.replace("\"", ""));


        if (splittedDataPart.endsWith("\"")) {
            data.add(sb.toString());
            sb.setLength(0);//clearing
        }
    }
```

Comment: And if a delimited element contains two commas?

Comment: Could you please put here that example and your expectation? I can change my code as well

Comment: Well, I would expect that the string `"Hi, \"hello, hola, ciao\""` should be split into two strings: `"Hi"` and `"hello, hola, ciao"`. I think your code would produce a different result.

Comment: No, but I updated my code. It should now do what is expected

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works you have to do it step by step. Check what comes next (comma or double quotes) and cut the next word.

```
public static String[] split(String s) {
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();

    int begin = 0;
    while (begin < s.length()) {
        int nextQuotes = s.indexOf("\"\"", begin);
        if (nextQuotes == begin) {
            l.add(s.substring(begin + 2, s.indexOf("\"\"", begin + 2)));
            begin = s.indexOf("\"\"", begin + 2) + 2;
            continue;
        }
        int nextComma = s.indexOf(',', begin);
        if (nextComma == begin) {
            l.add("");
            begin++;
            continue;
        } else if (nextComma == -1) {
            l.add(s.substring(begin));
            begin = s.length();
            continue;
        }
        l.add(s.substring(begin, nextComma));
        begin = nextComma + 1;
    }
    return l.toArray(new String[] {});
}
```

Not the best solution but it works.